# separating multiple elements within a string

Tags: php, mysql

how do you separate multiple elements within a string?

I am working on transferring information from a legacy database into a new table. one of the columns within the old table contains a long string with several header within it.

there are thousands of such records. I know how to use php/mysql to loop over each of these strings contained in the column. However , i am not sure how to go about extracting the data below each header within the string place its content  in a new column.

please note that the headers are the same for each record 
i.e

**Section One,**

**section two.**

so, I basically need to extract the data below section one and place within its own column and do the same for the other sections.

> **section One?**
>
> I enjoy connecting with people and tuning it to what is around them
>
> **Section Two?**
>
> so they receive the right guidance to resolve issues around them and
>   to     encourage and inspire.
>
> **Section Three?**
>      I believe that every reading should be uplifting and positive and when someone feels that,
>
> **Section four ?**
>
> When I wrote the first code for Facebook in January 2004, I hoped it would help students at my college connect and bring our community together.

UPDATE- I HAVE enclosed the tables

**LEGACY TABLE**

this is table from where the data is extracted;
we will extract the information from the **profile** column

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `readers` (
  `id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `profile` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1778 ;
```

**NEW TABLE**

this is the table that the data will go to. there are 6 columns. so the data from section One will enter column one etc.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `reader_personal_details` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `question1` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `question2` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `question3` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `question4` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `question5` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `question6` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

UPDATE TWO;
i just noticed that the headers are incased in HTML CODE . will this make a difference to the answer.

i.e

```
<p><strong>Section One?</strong></p>

<p><strong>i enjoy connecting with people and turning into what is around them ?</strong></p>
```

Comment: How do you recognise what you want to separate the elements by?

Comment: @Nyranith . hello Nyranith  at the end of each seperator there is a question mark  "?" . so, it will be safe to use this as the seperator. also, each title is the same. so, its safe to place all element that follow "section one" in the same column

Comment: Does each record have ALL the sections?

Comment: Hi Kickstart- yes all the records have exactly the same sections with exactly the same names

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution in SQL. Not 100% happy with it.

Set up a table containing all the headings in order (ie, either with the id as in the order they appear, or with a separate order field)

Then join your table of data with this twice, once to get the heading, and one to get the next heading that exists (using MIN).

Use this as a sub query and join back against your table to actually extract the values from your field.

Note that this will not work properly if the headings are repeated (ie, if a heading also appears in the text).

```
SELECT z.id, y.id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(COALESCE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(z.full_field, x.section_name, 1), z.full_field), y.section_name, -1)
FROM some_table z
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT a.id AS some_id, b.id AS first_header_id, MIN(c.id) AS second_header_id
    FROM some_table a
    INNER JOIN sections b ON INSTR(a.full_field, b.section_name) > 0
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sections c ON c.id > b.id
    GROUP BY some_id, first_header_id 
) sub0
ON z.id = sub0.some_id
INNER JOIN sections y ON y.id = sub0.first_header_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sections x ON x.id = sub0.second_header_id
```

I tested that with the following tables:-

```
CREATE TABLE sections
(
    id  INT,
    section_name    VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO sections VALUES
(1, 'section One?'),
(2, 'Section Two?'),
(3, 'Section Three?'),
(4, 'Section four ?');


CREATE TABLE some_table
(
    id  INT,
    full_field  TEXT
);

INSERT INTO some_table VALUES
(1, 'section One?

I enjoy connecting with people and tuning it to what is around them

Section Two?

so they receive the right guidance to resolve issues around them and to encourage and inspire.

Section Three?
I believe that every reading should be uplifting and positive and when someone feels that,

Section four ?

When I wrote the first code for Facebook in January 2004, I hoped it would help students at my college connect and bring our community together.');
```

EDIT

If you just want to output to fixed columns and the delimiters are fixed then it should be fairly easy, as follows:-

```
INSERT INTO reader_personal_details (`id`, `question1`, `question2`, `question3`, `question4`, `question5`, `question6`)
SELECT id,
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(profile, 'Section Two?', 1), 'section One?', -1),
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(profile, 'Section Three?', 1), 'section Two?', -1),
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(profile, 'Section four ?', 1), 'Section Three?', -1),
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(profile, 'Section Five?', 1), 'Section four ?', -1),
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(profile, 'Section Six?', 1), 'section Five?', -1),
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(profile, 'section Six?', -1)
FROM readers
```

Comment: hi Kickstart. sorry. i don't think I explained properly. the heading you refer to are all within the text. I basically need to go into each text/string and extract the data that is directly below each heading and then place this information in a separate column

Comment: The above query does extract each section for a piece of text (one section per returned row). With a normalised database I would expect to extract each section to a row of the target table. Can you put your table declares in the question (both the source and the destination).

Comment: hi Kickstart. i have updated my question to include the tables. thanks for your help so far

Comment: Added a simple solution for that

Comment: hello kickstart- thanks for the code. i will give it a try. quick qestion. i just noticed that the questions are enclased in html code. will that make a diffrence. i enclose above the html code

Comment: It will just treat it as text, with the HTML being part of the text. Hence you will need to include the HTML in the delimiters you specify.